# Python-Reading a string from a file, performing operations, reading the next string and performing the same operations

Tags: python

Im fairly new to python, I want to read a string from a file input that text using adb shell input text then go to the next line read the next string and input the next string by using the same command and this goes on for 200 lines

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: try a `for` loop. `with open('file', 'r') as fp: for line in fp: do whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem, note the use of the readlines method:

```
your_file = open('path to your file', 'r')  #this will open your file

lines = your_file.readlines()               #this is an array of lines

for line in lines:                          #loop over the lines
    <block of operations>
```